# Binary Search algorithm implementations

Tags: arrays, algorithm, binary-search

I have come across multiple problems which use variations of **binary search** to reach the final answer. These problems include finding floor of square root of number, checking if number is a perfect square or not, finding minimum in rotated array, finding first index of number in array etc.

All algorithms contain a low, high and mid variable which are appropriately modified.

I read several variations of these algorithms online and there are always high chances of by one error in these algorithms, causing it to miss the corner cases. For the following variations, is there any standard which can help me understand which one should be used when?

**1. Initialisation of variables**

Option1: low = 0, high = arr.length

Option2: low = 0, high = arr.length - 1

Option1: low = 1, high = arr.length

**2. Condition for loop**

Option1: while(low < high)

Option2: while(low <= high)

**3. Mid variable calculation**

Option1: mid = (low + high) / 2;

Option2: mid = low + (high - low) / 2;

**4. Condition Checking and updates to low and high**

Option1: low = mid AND high = mid

Option2: low = mid AND high = mid - 1

Option3: low = mid + 1 AND high = mid

Option4: low = mid + 1 AND high = mid - 1

EDIT: Assumptions taken are 3 state output. Array indices start at 0.

Comment: Several combinations of these options will lead to a correct algorithm. It also depends if array indices start at 0 or 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can make it work in lots of ways, but:

1) I use `low=0, high=arr.length`.  If I'm going to call variables `low` and `high`, then I want `low<=high` always, even at the end of the search.  This is also easier to think about when `arr.length==0`

2) `while (low<high)`.  This corresponds to the answer for (1).  When the loop is done, I like `low==high`, so I don't have to worry about which one to use.

3) Always use `mid=low+(high-low)/2` or `mid = low+((high-low)>>1)`.  The other option overflows when the array gets too long and gives negative results.

4) This depends on what kind of comparison you're using (3-state vs. 2-state output), in addition to the other answers.  For 2-state compares and the above-answers, you get `low=mid+1` or `high=mid`.  This is ideal, since it's obvious that the range gets smaller every iteration -- `mid+1 > low` obviously, and `mid < high`, because `low<high` (that's the loop condition) and `(high-low)/2` rounds downward.

Answer (score 2):

It's not like there are worse and better options that you've mentioned. Usually it just depends on a implementation, e.g. if you pass `high=arr.length` then you'd rather write `while(low < high)` than `while(low <= high)`.

In fact, some of those **differences may have a meaning**. If we consider binary search algorithm to find your X number in an array A and there will be some (not only one) elements equal to X, you can both find index of the first one or the last one - it depends on a implementation.

Comment: Yes true, I agree with you on that. But what is the best way to decide for any such question in general, so as to avoid missing corner cases?

Comment: If you ain't got specified that you have to find exactly FIRST or LAST index or something like that - go with your flow, write binsearch yourself in the way you understand it. If you'd understand what your code does - you will be able to adjust it to special case easily.