# Reduction of search space in binary search

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search

I am solving the [classical binary search problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-search/):

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    int search(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        if(nums.empty()) return -1;

        int lo=0, hi=nums.size()-1;
        while(lo<hi) {
            int mid=lo+(hi-lo)/2;
            //if element found at position mid, return mid
            if(nums[mid]==target) return mid;
            if(nums[mid]<target) lo=mid+1;
            //why not hi=mid-1, since if mid _could_ have our answer, we would 
            //have already returned above
            else hi=mid;
        }
        
        // if element not found, return -1;
        return nums[lo]==target ? lo : -1;
    }
};
```

I am seeking an intuitive explanation for setting `hi=mid` (specifically with the while loop condition as `lo<hi` and not `lo<=hi`).  I think we should set it as `hi=mid-1`, since we know that `mid` cannot contain our answer (if it did, then we would have already returned).  Yes, I can try it out on a few examples, but I am trying to intuitively understand how the search space reduces while *developing the logic* (before getting to coding) so that I can come up with a concrete algo that can work on all examples.

Comment: If `nums` is empty, you have a very big problem.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, yes, true.  I have edited the code.  Thanks for pointing that out! :)

Comment: Look again at what you wrote. Setting `hi=mid` with `lo<hi` describes the current situation that you do not understand, and `hi=mid-1` with `lo<=hi` describes the situation you think would work better. Can you come up with a case where these situations have different functionality?

Comment: @JaMiT, do you mean when `lo==hi`?

Comment: @Someone OK, I should have asked for a case *plus* an explanation of how the functionality differs. What happens when `lo==hi` in the two situations?

Comment: The reason for the problem Paul mentioned is precisely because you're preferring an inclusive high-side. The added check would not be required if you weren't doing that. That alone is already an accounting for why a fully inclusive window leads to extra work.

Comment: @WhozCraig, could you please elaborate?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39221303/binary-search-algorithm-implementations, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39416560/how-can-i-simplify-this-working-binary-search-code-in-c/39417165#39417165

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am seeking an intuitive explanation for setting `hi=mid` (specifically with the while loop condition as `lo<hi` and not `lo<=hi`). I think we should set it as `hi=mid-1`, since we know that `mid` cannot contain our answer (if it did, then we would have already returned).

There are two main potential issues here:

1. Correctness.  Does the function terminate, returning the correct answer, for all inputs?

   - with `hi=mid`, yes.  For this, we can observe that when the loop condition `lo<hi` holds, `mid` is always strictly less than `hi` but not less than `lo`, therefore setting `mid=hi` reduces the search interval.  We can also observe that when that alternative is exercised, the target value must be in the reduced interval if it is present at all.  Since the search space is finite and is reduced at every iteration, the computation must eventually reach an interval size of 1 (and therefore terminate) if it does not find the target sooner.
   - with `hi=mid-1`, also yes.  The argument is the same, but it is worth noting that it can be the case that `mid == lo`, which yields the possibility that `hi` would be set less than `lo`.  That does not present a practical problem as the function is written, but it is a bit untidy.
2. Efficiency.  Could the function arrive at the correct result in fewer steps?

   Using `hi=mid-1` does not make the function *asymptotically* faster.  It is O(log n) either way.  Moreover, on any given problem, the two alternatives will test different sequences of values, so either alternative might happen to complete in fewer cycles than the other when the target value is present.  Intuition suggests that shrinking the search interval that little bit more would be a slight win on average, especially in the case where the target value is not present, but that gain is proportionally insignificant except for in the cycles where the interval is already pretty small.

> I am trying to intuitively understand how the search space reduces while developing the logic (before getting to coding) so that I can come up with a concrete algo that can work on all examples.

Either alternative works, and there is no reason to expect a noticeable speed difference.  It comes down, then, to style and personal sensibility.  Myself, I prefer `hi=mid` in this case so as to avoid ever producing a situation where `hi < lo`.  Others might prefer `hi=mid-1` for symmetry.

---

Side note: one cannot, on the other hand, change from `lo=mid+1` to `lo=mid`.  Because it is possible for `mid=lo+(hi-lo)/2` to result in `mid==lo`, one needs the `lo=mid+1` alternative to ensure that the interval shrinks on every cycle.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Did not follow the side note.  Do you mean `lo=mid+1` and `lo=mid` instead?

Comment: Yes, @Someone, you're right.  I accidentally performed a variable swap there, which I have now fixed.