# Is it a pattern determine what index variable to be used in binary search?

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, binary-search

When doing https://leetcode.com/problems/search-insert-position. I found that it is hard to determine the combination of index variable.

For example, we have following combination in each level of the code.

```
(1)
l = 0 (stable)
r = len; r = len-1; (outbound / inbound)

(2)
loop(l < r); loop(l <= r) (outbound / inbound)

(3)
l = ind+1 (stable)
r = ind; r = ind-1 (include / exclude)
```

so now you have different combination of index variable, some of them are working, but if you change one of them, it will not pass all test cases

```
combo 1:
l=0, r=len (outbound); loop(l < r); l=ind+1, r=ind (include); work

combo 2:
l=0, r=len-1 (inbound); loop(l < r); l=ind+1, r=ind (include); !work

combo 3:
l=0, r=len (inbound); loop(l < r); l=ind+1, r=ind-1 (exclude); !work

combo 4:
l=0, r=len (outbound); loop(l < r); l=ind+1, r=ind (include); work

combo 5:
l=0, r=len-1 (inbound); loop(l<=r); l=ind+1, r=ind (include); work

comb 6:
l=0, r=len (outbound); recursive(l<=r); l=ind+1, r=ind (include); work
```

Below is the code I play around. Some of them are working and some of them are not working

```
// sm: l=0, r=len (outbound); loop(l < r); l=ind+1, r=ind (include); work
var searchInsert = function (ns, tar) {
  let l = 0;
  let r = ns.length; // outbound
  let ind;

  while (l < r) {
    ind = Math.floor((l + r) / 2);

    if (ns[ind] < tar) {
      l = ind + 1;
    } else if (ns[ind] > tar) {
      r = ind;
    } else {
      return ind; // existed
    }
  }

  return l; // insert
};

// sm: l=0, r=len-1 (inbound); loop(l < r); l=ind+1, r=ind (include); !work
var searchInsert = function (ns, tar) {
  let l = 0;
  let r = ns.length - 1; // inbound, cannot insert outbound
  let ind;

  while (l < r) {
    ind = Math.floor((l + r) / 2);

    if (ns[ind] < tar) {
      l = ind + 1;
    } else if (ns[ind] > tar) {
      r = ind;
    } else {
      return ind; // existed
    }
  }

  return l; // insert
};

// sm: l=0, r=len (inbound); loop(l < r); l=ind+1, r=ind-1 (exclude); !work
var searchInsert = function (ns, tar) {
  let l = 0;
  let r = ns.length;
  let ind;

  while (l < r) {
    ind = Math.floor((l + r) / 2);

    if (ns[ind] < tar) {
      l = ind + 1;
    } else if (ns[ind] > tar) {
      r = ind - 1;
    } else {
      return ind; // existed
    }
  }

  return l; // insert
};

// sm: l=0, r=len (outbound); loop(l < r); l=ind+1, r=ind (include); work
var searchInsert = function (ns, tar) {
  let l = 0;
  let r = ns.length;
  let ind;

  while (l < r) {
    ind = Math.floor((l + r) / 2);

    if (ns[ind] < tar) {
      l = ind + 1;
    } else if (ns[ind] > tar) {
      r = ind;
    } else {
      return ind; // existed
    }
  }

  return l; // insert
};

// sm: l=0, r=len-1 (inbound); loop(l<=r); l=ind+1, r=ind (include); work
var searchInsert = function (ns, tar) {
  let l = 0;
  let r = ns.length - 1;
  let ind;

  while (l <= r) {
    ind = Math.floor((l + r) / 2);

    if (ns[ind] < tar) {
      l = ind + 1;
    } else if (ns[ind] > tar) {
      r = ind - 1;
    } else {
      return ind; // existed
    }
  }

  return l; // insert
};

// sm: l=0, r=len (outbound); recurive(l<=r); l=ind+1, r=ind (include); work
var searchInsert = function (ns, tar) {
  let l = 0;
  let r = ns.length;
  return recur(ns, l, r, tar);
};

var recur = function (ns, l, r, tar) {
  if (l >= r) {
    return l;
  }

  const ind = Math.floor((l + r) / 2);

  if (ns[ind] === tar) {
    return ind;
  } else if (ns[ind] < tar) {
    return recur(ns, ind + 1, r, tar);
  } else if (ns[ind] > tar) {
    return recur(ns, l, ind, tar);
  }
};

const ns = [1, 3, 5, 6];
const tar = 5;
const out = searchInsert(ns, tar);
console.log(out);
```

My question is that, when you are presented a binary search question? How do you know which index combo you are going to use? Because it is really depend on the problem, trail and error

Comment: Why do you think combo2 do not work? I tried it on LeetCode and it worked.

Comment: In combo 3, should it be inbound or outbound? I tested both on LeetCode and both passed. Did you use something else to test the solutions?

Comment: @LearningMathematics [1,3,5,6], 7 failed. For combo 2, did you copy and paste the code? Did you use javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binary Search algorithm implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39221303/binary-search-algorithm-implementations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a very common question for people who just started learning binary search.  I will try to analyze your examples case-by-case to see if you can understand better.

### Rephrasing

It's helpful to rephrase the problem first. If we set `ns[ns.length]`
to `infinity`, the problem is essentially asking you to find the first `i` such that `ns[i] >= tar`.

### Idea

Consider the array `[1, 3, 5, 6]` and `tar = 5`, using the above definition on each element, we can see that the array can actually be evaluated to `[F, F, T, T]`, so what we need to do is to just to find the index of the first `T`. The same can be applied to any arrays.

### Implementation

Now here comes to the core of the problem. I will first illustrate why combo 2 and 3 do not work.

In combo 2,
`l=0, r=len-1 (inbound); loop(l < r); l=ind+1, r=ind (include);`:
We can see that `r` is initilised to `len - 1`. However, what if the array given evaluates to `[F, F, F, F]`? The answer is `4` but r is initialized to `3`, meaning that `4` will never be considered as an answer.

In combo 3, `l=0, r=len (inbound); loop(l < r); l=ind+1, r=ind-1 (exclude);`:
We can see that `r=ind-1` if `ns[ind] > tar`. However, we want to find the first `i` such that `ns[ind] >= tar` so `ns[ind]` will still be a potential candidate! It is therefore incorrect to exclude it in this stage.

An example to consider is `[3, 4, 5]` and `tar = 4`. In the first iteration, `ind = 1` and `4` gets eliminated immediately, which should be the correct answer.

You can verify that other combo works fine by seeing if your binary search will eliminate potential candidates wrongly.

### Additional notes

As you have said, using which index combo really depends on the problem. However, in this particular problem, if I am asked to find the first `i` such that `ns[i] >= tar`, I would have a cleaner implementation as follows:

```
var searchInsert = function (ns, tar) {
  let l = 0;
  let r = ns.length;
  let ind;
  ns.push(Infinity);
  while (l < r) {
    ind = Math.floor((l + r) / 2);
    if (ns[ind] >= tar) {
      r = ind;
    } else {
      l = ind + 1;
    }
  }
  return r; // insert
};
```

which is just finding the first `T` in the array.