# binary search right should be nums.length or nums.length - 1?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search

I'm always confused with Binary search right boarder.
For example, if we want to find the last index of target in a sorted array, the code should be:

```
public int binarySearchLarger(int[] nums, int target) {
        int l = 0;
        int r = nums.length - 1;
        while (l < r) {
            int m = l + (r - l + 1) / 2;
            if (nums[m] < target) l = m;
            else if(nums[m] > target) r = m - 1;
            else l = m;
        }
        if (nums[l] == target) return l;
        else return -1;
    }
```

but I see lots of posts said that if we want while(l<r), then r should be nums.length, in this case, the code becomes:

```
public int binarySearchLarger(int[] nums, int target) {
        int l = 0;
        int r = nums.length;
        while (l < r) {
            int m = l + (r - l + 1) / 2;
            if (nums[m] < target) l = m;
            else if(nums[m] > target) r = m - 1;
            else l = m;
        }
        if (nums[l] == target) return l;
        else return -1;
    }
```

but in this case, `if (nums[m] < target) l = m;` will throw arrayindexoutofbound exception.
My questions is: when should we use `r = nums.length - 1` and when should we use `r = nums.length?`

Comment: Java array indexes are counted from 0 to length-1. Other languages may start from 1 to length. So, it depends on the language. In your case, you are probably geting the out of bounds exception trying to access the "length'th" element of the array...

Comment: If you're quoting code, please link to it so we can see the exact algorithm. If you take a correct binary search that assumes `length - 1` and you make it `length`, yes, it'll crash. But there are other changes you can make to the algorithm that make it possible to treat the rightmost bound exclusively rather than inclusively and still be correct. If you show exactly where you saw these algorithms it'll be easier to explain how the difference works without speculating.

Comment: If the code always chooses `l = m;`, then `r` will never change, and eventually `l` has to be equal to `r` (since that's the only way that the loop to end). When `l == r` and `m == r` and `r == nums.length` you'll get the index-out-of-bounds error because `num[m]` is `num[nums.length]`. Long story short, you need to check the math with some examples. Make sure it works for odd length and even length arrays. Make sure it works when `l` never changes and `r` never changes. Make sure it works when `l == r-1`.

Answer (score 1):

See this answer for a discussion about the various options when implementing binary search: [Binary Search algorithm implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39221303/binary-search-algorithm-implementations/39227182#39227182)

For your problem, which seems to be to find the last instance of the target, I do it like this:

```
int findLastIndexOfTarget(int[] nums, int toFind) {
    // find the position that divides <= toFind from > toFind
    // these are the lowest and highest possible indexes
    int low = 0;
    int high = nums.length;
    // while there is a range of possible indexes
    while(low<high) {
        int test = low+((high-low)/2);
        if (nums[test] <= toFind) {
            //too low
            low = test+1; //guaranteed > low, <= high
        } else {
            //not too low
            high = test;  //guaranteed >= low, < high 
        }
    }
    // guaranteed low == high
    // We found the position we were looking for. See if the target is on the left
    return (low > 0 && nums[low-1]==target) ? low-1 : -1;
}
```