# What's the differences between binary search algorithm's templates?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search

On Leetcode, there are three different templates for binary search. I can understand the first one which goes through the element of the array and update the index position (but why in the while loop it is left <= right instead of left < right); however, the next two templates are not clear for me. I don't know why we put the right index equal to len(array) instead of len(array) - 1, and why we use right = mid as searching left. The third template while loop is using left + 1 < right in the while loop and putting the mid = left as searching right and right = mid as searching left. Could you please explain the differences between these three templates? I'm also confused about the post-processing steps.

**Template 1**

```
def binary_Search(nums, target):

    if len(nums) == 0:
        return -1

    left, right = 0, len(nums) - 1
    while left <= right:
        mid = (left + right) // 2
        if nums[mid] == target:
            return mid
        elif nums[mid] < target:
            left = mid + 1
        else:
            right = mid - 1

    # End Condition: left > right
    return -1
```

**Template 2**

```
def binarySearch(nums, target):

    if len(nums) == 0:
        return -1

    left, right = 0, len(nums)
    while left < right:
        mid = (left + right) // 2
        if nums[mid] == target:
            return mid
        elif nums[mid] < target:
            left = mid + 1
        else:
            right = mid

    # Post-processing:
    # End Condition: left == right
    if left != len(nums) and nums[left] == target:
        return left
    return -1
```

**Template 3**

```
def binarySearch(nums, target):

    if len(nums) == 0:
        return -1

    left, right = 0, len(nums) - 1
    while left + 1 < right:
        mid = (left + right) // 2
        if nums[mid] == target:
            return mid
        elif nums[mid] < target:
            left = mid
        else:
            right = mid

    # Post-processing:
    # End Condition: left + 1 == right
    if nums[left] == target: return left
    if nums[right] == target: return right
    return -1
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? the best way to learn..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39221303/binary-search-algorithm-implementations