# binary search length issue: confused if end length should be is total length of array or length of array-1

Tags: java, algorithm, search, data-structures, computer-science

```
import java.util.*;
public class BinarySearc {

    public static int bsearch(int numbers[], int key) {
        int start = 0, end = numbers.length-1;

        while(start<=end) {
            int mid = (start + end)/2;

            // comparisions
            if(numbers[mid]==key) {
                return mid;
            }
            else if(numbers[mid]<key) {   
                start=mid+1;
            }
            else {
                end=mid-1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int numbers[] = {1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 18, 20};
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in) ;
        System.out.print("Enter value: ");
        int value = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("index for the value is: "+bsearch(numbers, value));
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

I was writing code for binary search, and this is the code I wrote but initially to find the mid of the array I used start = 0 and end = length of array i.e numbers.length which seems to work fine for this array, yet I saw many online code examples that used the value of end as (total array length - 1) i.e here numbers.length - 1.
Can someone explain why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39221303/binary-search-algorithm-implementations/39227182#39227182

Answer (score 0):

Using `numbers.length` happened to work for your test case on your code only because you found a value in the array without attempting to search beyond the end of your array.  If you search for e.g. `24` (an value greater than any that exist in the array) while initializing `end` to `numbers.length`, then you'll get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when the code eventually assigns the value of `numbers.length` to `mid` and you access the array.

You should always initialize `end` to the length of your array minus one, as you have it in your code here, because that is the index of the last element in the array.  This will prevent your code's implementation of the binary search algorithm from attempting to access elements of the array that don't exist.